# Beracha Achronah on milk

Tags: blessing, eretz-yisrael, dairy

We say a special Beracha Achronah on the seven species that Eretz Yisroel is praised in the Possuk Eretz Zeis Shemen etc. 
My question is, since Eretz Yisroel is also praised with milk (albeit in other Pesukkim) as the Possuk says Eretz Zovas Cholov Udevash, why is there no special Beracha Achronah for milk?

Answer (score 1):

On wine, grains and fruit one can be "Kove`a SeUda" meaning on can make a filling meal out of it or when someone comes to visit that is what is served. Milk is not in that catagory.

There is an opinion that the milk mentioned is white wine.
http://www.ou.org/torah/article/tzarich_iyun_milk_and_honey

Comment: Please prove that one can be Koveia Seudah on fruit. Besides, you have not answered why the Chachomim didn't make any distinction for milk.

Comment: THe Nishmas Adam in Hilchos Sukah says that one can eat fruit outside of the suckah even if one was Koveia Seudah so we see that fruit is something that people make a meal out of. http://98.131.138.124/articles/NA2/NishmatAbraham.OC.639.asp Al HaMichia is a form of Birkat HaMazon so just like Birkat HaMazon needs Keviat Seudah so does Al HaMichia. When a guest comes over you might sit with them over a cup of wine, cake, or fruit. Not milk.

Comment: Please answer the question "why?"

Comment: Since being mentioned in the pasuk was not enough to mandate it's own bracha. Keviat Seuda + fruits of Eretz Yisroel is.

Comment: Also, the M'chilta d'Rashbi ([13:5](http://books.google.com/books?id=jV0pAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=%22%D7%96%D7%94+%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%91+%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%22#v=onepage&q=%22%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%91%20%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%22&f=false)) cites R' Eliezer as saying that "chalav" refers to "milk" of fruits.

Comment: @Fred that's good. But the Gemara (Bechoros 6a) learns from the Possuk Zovas Cholov that milk is permissible and not Aiver Min Hachai. Also see Megilah 6a especially what Rashi explains how EY flows with honey and milk.

Comment: @eramm Using your argument, the Shelah in Maseches Shabbos Perek Ner Mitzvah 6 speaks about Kevius Seudah of ma'acholei Cholov for a Bris during the 9 days.

Comment: @MeirZirkind: Fruit is bedieved ok for shalos seudos, necessary when erev pesach falls on shabbes.

Comment: @NBZ I don't get your point. Also, meat and fish could also be used!

Comment: @MZ The Shulchan Aruch HaRav specifically mentions fruit.

Comment: @MZ ma'acholei Cholov is not the same as the cup of milk in the original question.